# Is there a strongly connected graph where 2 vertices exist such that random walk from one to another requires more than polynomial time?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, expected-value, computational-complexity, random-walk

The question is fairly simple: find an example of strongly connected (directed) graph $G$ on n vertices, such that degree of every vertice is at least $\frac{n}{2}$ and there exists a pair of vertices $(s, t)$ such that random walk from $s$ to $t$ takes more than polynomial time. I don't have any clues to solving this problem, so any help will be great!

Comment: By "degree", do you mean in-degree or out-degree or the sum of the two?

Comment: @karl, sum of the two

Comment: In that case, it should be easy to make it difficult to reach $t$. Do you have any ideas?